# Setting empty value for Custom Attribute with Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've set up a custom sign up and a profile edit policy with Azure AD B2C. I created a custom attribute that a user can fill out. It's optional. However, I ran into a problem that if a user sets a value for this attribute during sign up they cannot remove that value and replace it with an empty string. B2C will dismiss this empty value and leave the original value untouched. Only if a user sets a different non-empty value that value gets persisted.

Comment: Any update of this issue?

Comment: Any update for this? Getting same issue.

Comment: We have experienced this issue. Unfortunately Microsoft support has not been able to provide an answer, but nor will they accept that it's an unsupported scenario.

Comment: Are you using User Flows or Identity Experience Framework - I believe in the latter it works as you expect.

Comment: I'm using the identity experience framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your custom policies, you need to add a metadata item in to the technical profiles you want to receive null values from claims. In the scenario you outline, if you update the `SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate` technical profile (assuming this is the technical profile your EditProfile user flow references) with this metadata item, you should be able to update an attribute and receive a null claim back, meaning the attribute gets cleared in AAD. Here is the metadata item to add:

```
<Item Key="AllowGenerationOfClaimsWithNullValues">true</Item>
```

Give this a shot and let me know if it resolves your issue.

Comment: You can indent the code portion of your answer, or use triple backticks, to format it as code so those `<>` will print as they should. See [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for the exact guidelines.